Optimizing Cypher Query to Find Specific Cycles in a Graph Database
I am working with a Neo4j graph database where I have a specific type of node, let's call them Device. Each Device node has a type property that can be either "A", "B", or "C". Nodes are connected with a single type of bidirectional relationship.
I need to find all cycles in the graph starting and ending with a node of type "B", with the condition that every step in between only connects through nodes of type "C".
Here's the Cypher query I've come up with:
MATCH (start:Device {type: "B"})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {
    relationshipFilter: "CONNECTED_TO>",
    labelFilter: ">Device",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 9999,
    uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH'
}) YIELD path
WHERE LENGTH(path) >= 3
      AND ALL(node IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE node.type = "C")
      AND last(nodes(path)).type = 'B'
      AND id(start) <= id(last(nodes(path)))
RETURN path


This query works, but it's slow—taking over 20 seconds for a graph with 200 nodes and 800 relationships. How can I optimize this query to run more efficiently?

hi @user24347415; can you give us sample data to work with? Thanks.

@jose_bacoy I'm sorry I haven't replied yet. I'm too busy to organize a new set of data. My current data belongs to the company, and I'm still learning how to create some data that meets the requirements. I may provide it later. I apologize again

I've found a solution to my problem. Since my requirements were quite specific, instead of creating nodes of the same type with different "type" properties, I decided to create distinct node labels for each type. I then used the labelFilter parameter in the apoc.path.expandConfig function to filter the nodes accordingly. Here's how I revised my Cypher query:
MATCH (start:B_Device)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {
    relationshipFilter: "CONNECTED_TO>",
    labelFilter: "+C_Device|/B_Device",
    minLevel: 1,
    maxLevel: 9999,
    uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH'
}) YIELD path
WHERE LENGTH(path) >= 3
      AND ALL(node IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE node.type = "C")
      AND last(nodes(path)).type = 'B'
      AND id(start) <= id(last(nodes(path)))
RETURN path

This modification reduced the execution time from over 20 seconds to less than 1 millisecond. Incredible improvement!

This does not return simple cycles (a cycle beginning and ending on the same node) which your problem statement requires. See my answer for more of an explanation.

@FinbarGood It's doesn't metter ,I write another CQL to get the cycle which start = end:
MATCH (start:B_Device)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {
    relationshipFilter: "CONNECTED_TO>",
    labelFilter: "+C_Device|>C_Device",
    // sequence: "",
    minLevel: 2,
    maxLevel: 9999,
    uniqueness: 'NODE_PATH'
}) YIELD path
WITH path, start, last(nodes(path)) AS end
WHERE 
    EXISTS((end)-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(start))
RETURN path


This query can be re-written simply below:
MATCH path=(start:Device {type: "B"})-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(Device {type: "C"})-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(end:Device {type: "B"})
WHERE LENGTH(path) >= 3  AND elementId(start) <= elementId(end)
RETURN path

The reason is

node IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE node.type = "C" is the same as saying that all nodes between start and end node is type "C". This is converted into [:CONNECTED_TO*]
last(nodes(path)).type = 'B' is the same as (end:Device {type: "B"})

Please test this out and let me know if it works for you.

This doesn't enforce the requirement that paths only go via C nodes, as the var-length relationship -[:CONNECTED_TO*]-> only filters on the relationship types, not the node labels. Your pattern only enforces that the penultimate node has label C.

try it with sample test data and you will see what this line means:
ALL(node IN nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE node.type = "C").
It is the same as [:CONNECTED_TO*]->(Device {type: "C"})

That's not how the query you posted works. Did you forget to include all() predicate function?

Note in the following I've incorporated the OP's own suggested improvement of using labels A_Device, B_Device and C_Device instead of type property, as this improves performance.
Your question states that you are looking for cycles, which would require at least one node to appear more than once in your path. And if you are looking for simple cycles, then the first and last node in a path are the same.
But paths returned by apoc.path.expandConfig() with uniqueness:NODE_PATH will not return any cycles as such.
Take the following simple graph as an illustration:

There are two simple cycles that begin and end with B_Device nodes and that only traverse via C_Device nodes:
(1)-->(2)-->(3)-->(4)-->(1)
(1)-->(2)-->(4)-->(1)

The following path doesn't qualify because it re-traverses node with id 2:
(1)-->(2)-->(3)-->(2)-->(4)-->(1)

To get the answers you specify in your question, you can use a quantified path pattern:
MATCH path = (start:B_Device) 
             (()-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(m:C_Device)){2,} 
             ()-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(start)
WHERE size(m) = size(COLLECT { WITH m UNWIND m AS _ RETURN DISTINCT _ })
RETURN path

The WHERE clause ensures that no nodes are repeated in the variable m, which holds all the nodes between the start / end node. This will discard some paths that end up being traversed, but the same is true for apoc.path.expandConfig() as there is no uniqueness node for simple cycles.

{2,} is not correct.  The conditions says "ALL devices between B should be type "C".
Besides the start should not be the same with the end of the devices.

The quantified path pattern ensures that all intermediate nodes are labelled C_Device. This incorporates the OP's own answer, which improves things by elevating the type properties to labels. The lower bound is 2 because there is a final 'leg' of the path after the quantified path pattern.
On your second point, I am taking this statement on face value: I need to find all cycles in the graph starting and ending with a node of type "B". The OP can clarify, but I took that to mean a simple cycle, and explained that in my answer.
